# Discrete Time Filtered White Noise

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, white-noise

Theoretically, the variance of a filtered white noise should be:
$$\sigma^2  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2\,\mathrm df = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{PSD}_{\text{new}}(f)\,\mathrm df$$

So practically:

1. I should be able to calculate the variance from the PSD estimate of the filtered white noise?
2. What will be the correct way to convert this integral to a discrete sum?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> I should be able to calculate the variance from the PSD estimate of the filtered white noise?

Yes. Since there's zero-measure sum at exactly 0 Hz, the expectation of the filter output $h(t)$ is 0, and thus the power of your signal is equal to its variance. And the integral over a power density is a power. So, yeah, if you integrate over the PSD for the whole frequency axis, you should get the signal power and thus the signal variance.

> What will be the correct way to convert this integral to a discrete sum?

The Sampling Theory for time-domain signals requires the frequency domain representation of that same signal to have a finite support (i.e., the signal must be *band-limited*) in order for it to be able to correctly represent it by a finite sum over weighted sampling functions. In the same way, it requires a signal to be time-limited (i.e. do not exist outside a compact interval in the time domain) for you to be able replace that integral by a discrete sum.

So, the correct way would be:

1. make sure your signal is time-limited. White noise passed through a filter is decidedly *not* time-limited, so here's where things break in the strict sense, and you can't correctly represent this particular signal by a sum. In a practical sense, we go, ignore this fact and simply assume the signal stopped after a long enough amount of time, $T_t$.
2. You sample your PSD every $\frac1{T_t}$, $\Phi[k] = \text{PSD}_{\text{new}}(k/T_T)$. You normalize with a factor of $\pi$, because that's the energy reconstructing interpolating scaled sin f/f (Shannon-Whittaker formula).

Comment: Thank you very much for your respone.
Did you assume my system is analog? how can one sample a PSD? (sorry if i misunderstood you)..
If my dealings are purely digital, i.e i generate wgn and pass it through a digital filter, i would only need to estimate the right PSD? with Welch's method or regular periodogram? and then integrate over it?